# Is $p_1p_2\ldots p_n +1$ a prime number for infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n,\ldots,$ be the sequence of prime numbers. Are there infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that the natural number $p_1p_2\ldots p_n +1$  is a prime number?

Comment: what if u can choose the enumeration?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242425/infinitely-many-primes-coming-from-euclids-proof?rq=1).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda  Thank  you  very  much for  sharing the question.

Answer (score 4):

From W. Narkiewicz, *The Development of Prime Number Theory*, p.3:

> There are 18 primes of this form with $p_n < 35000$ and it is not known whether there are infinitely many of them.

The book is roughly 20 years old so it may have changed but I highly doubt it.

Narkiewicz gives the following references for primality testing of elements of this sequence:

- Borning, A. (1972): Some results for $k! \pm 1$ and $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dots p +1$.
- Templer, M. (1980): On the primality of $k! + 1$ and $2 \cdot 3 \dots p + 1$.
- Buhler, J.P., Crandall, R.E., Penk, M.A. (1982): Primes of the form $n! \pm 1$ and $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dots p \pm 1$.
- Caldwell, C.K. (1995): On the primality of $n! \pm 1$ and $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dots p \pm 1$.

Comment: I added a few references given by Narkiewicz. It may lead to newer papers citing those.

Comment: See also my question https://mathoverflow.net/q/38794 .

Comment: Thank you and my +1 for  your interesting and informative answer